# How can I modify this jQuery XML parser?

Tags: jquery, html, css, xml

I have this news parser. I need to add images here. Hyperlinks for them will be parsed from XML. How can I upgrade my xmlParser? I need image inside div to give correct position for image via CSS. And CSS class assigned to div for this image.

I have tried to add

```
<div class="articleimg">' + <img src='"+$(this).find("image").text()+"'/> + '</div>
```

but it seems that I'm incorrect with syntax. How will the full line with append look after adding such code?

From head:

```
function xmlParser(xml) {

$('#load').fadeOut();

$(xml).find("item").each(function () {

    $(".main").append('<div class="article"><div class="title">' + $(this).find("title").text() + '</div><div class="full">' + $(this).find("description").html() + '</div><div class="date">Добавлена: ' + $(this).find("pubDate").text() + '</div></div>');
    $(".article").fadeIn(500);
});}
```

From body:

```
<div class="main">
<div id="loader" class="loader"><img src="../images/theme/loader.gif" alt="loader" id="load" width="64" height="64" style="vertical-align:middle;"/></div>
</div>
```

From xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rss xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0"
xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
<channel>
<item>
<title>Title</title>
<description>Description</description>
<image>http://website.com/images/news/news.png</image>
<pubDate>2018/03/10 00:00:00 GMT+3</pubDate>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: don't you have enough to go off of? You're building an element already, and you're querying the xml already, just add the right css selector and append the right text and you'll be good to go

Comment: @Isaac I have tried to add `<div class="articleimg">' + <img src='"+$(this).find("image").text()+"'/> + '</div>` but it seems that I'm incorrect with syntax. Please tell me how the full line with append will look after adding such code.

Comment: put that comment into the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you must update you **append()** in script with img tag. You just a little mistaken with your quotes ' and "

> '<div class="article"><div class="title">'

is inside ''. It's a string. It's Ok.

Next

> +<img src='"+$(this).find("image").text()+"'/> -

Here **<img src=** - looks like javascript code wich need to interpret. But it's also string with HTML. So you must wrap it in quotes.

Here are I marked stings as bold for better understanding. It's all inside '

+'**<img src="**'+$(this).find("image").text()+'**"/>**'

So your code is

```
$(".main").append('<div class="article"><div class="articleimg"><img src="'+$(this).find("image").text()+'"/></div><div class="title">' + $(this).find("title").text() + '</div><div class="full">' + $(this).find("description").html() + '</div><div class="date">Добавлена: ' + $(this).find("pubDate").text() + '</div></div>');
```

---

I removed excess quotes.

> '<div>'+'<img'+ variable +'>'+'</div>'

is same as

> '<div><img'+ variable +'><div>'